# How to handle [object Promise] in Discord.js google-images module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, discord.js

I recently installed a node module called google-images for my discord bot, I got a CSE set up and an API, but when I set it to print the result, it returns an `[Object Promise]` and I dont know how to make it output a link/image instead.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I've already tried using resolve() to try to resolve the promise, but I'm not very experienced with resolve(). It either doesn't return anything, or returns an [object Promise]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Promise.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).
When a promise is fulfilled, the value that it "returns" is passed as an argument to the function you put in `.then()`.

Here's an example:

```js
// This function returns a Promise
function takesTime() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res("I'm \"returning\" this value");
  });
}

takesTime() // returns a Promise
  .then(value => { // the function you put into then is like a callback
    // inside it you can do your stuff with the value
    console.log(value);
  }).catch(console.error); // if the Promise is not fulfilled, you can catch errors

//Since takesTime() returned its value (even if it is a Promise) this will run first.
console.log("I'm the first.");
```

If you need a good guide to approach Promises, you can check out [MDN's guide on Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) ;)